# Form ajax add more button added via another ajax callback not working

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I have a form button which I want to add another field with another button on that form( I am able to do this) but second button is not clickable. Any idea. Following is my code-

This is my form code-

```
function create_report_form($form, $form_state) {
$form['title'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Report ttitle'),
    '#value' =>'',
);

$form['actions'] = array(
  '#type' => 'actions',
);

$form['actions']['submit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Save'),
);
$form['conditions'] = array(
  '#tree' => TRUE,
);
$form['conditions']['report_type'] = array(
  '#title' => t('Report type'),
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#prefix'=> '<div class="conditions-wrapper"></div>',
  '#multiple' => false, 
  '#options' => get_report_type()
); 

 $form['conditions']['submit'] = array(
   '#type' => 'button',
   '#value' => t('Add condition'),
   //'#name' =>   '_add_another_outcome',
   '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'reports_add_conditions',
      'wrapper' => 'report-form',
      'method' => 'replace',
      'effect' => 'fade',
   ),
  );  
   return $form;
}
```

Now, when I click on this button it will call the following function and generate another form element(select list) with another button which will call another ajax function (this is what which is not working).

```
function reports_add_conditions($form, &$form_state){
$values = $form_state['values'];
$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
$type = $values['conditions']['report_type'];
$form['attributes'] = array(
  '#tree' => TRUE,
);
$form['attributes']['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'button',
    '#value' => t('Add attribute condition'),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'reports_add_attribute_conditions',
      'wrapper' => 'report-form',
      'method' => 'replace',
      'effect' => 'fade',
    ),
);       
$form['attributes']['attribute'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => '',
    '#options' => get_options($type),
    '#size' => 22, 
);  
  return drupal_render($form);
}
```

As you can see from the code I am not able to call "reports_add_attribute_conditions" function for the button.

This is my second call back code-

```
function reports_add_attribute_conditions($form, &$form_state){
$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
$values = $form_state['values'];
$type = $values['conditions']['report_type'];
$form['attribute'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#name' => $type,
    '#title' => '',
    '#options' =>  get_options($type),
    '#size' => 22, 
); 
$form['attributes']['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'button',
    '#value' => t('Add attribute condition'),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'reports_add_attribute_conditions',
      'wrapper' => 'report-form',
      'method' => 'replace',
      'effect' => 'fade',
    ),
); 

 return drupal_render($form);
}
```

Any idea is greatly appreciable

Comment: Are there errors in Drupal's logs, the browser JS console, or the web server's logs?

Comment: no errors. nothing in console not even showing the callback URL.

Comment: Have you tried just returning the $form array instead of rendering it first. The docs imply it shouldn't matter, but I've always returned the render array or one of the framework commands: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21ajax.inc/group/ajax_commands/7.x

Comment: you mean just  return  $form; right. Its still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@NabajitRoy my idea is

1. Never use `drupal_render()` manual calls (return $form array as-is)
2. Move all the form generation code into form constructor( `create_report_form()` ), AJAX
   callback should not create new elements for form but only
   `create_report_form()` should
3. AJAX callbacks should only return element form (not generate them)
   e.g. return `$form['attributes']['submit']` and may be
   `$form_state['rebuild'] = true;` if needed.
4. To know in `create_report_form()` if it was called by AJAX request
   button check the `$form_state['triggering_element']` in it.
5. I feel that using `'#type' => 'submit'` instead of `'#type' => 'button'`
   is better

[image: https://www.drupal.org/node/752056] https://www.drupal.org/node/752056

Comment: Thanks I will check this and let you know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

may AJAX request is not send to server at all? 
Try changin the

```
$form['attributes']['submit'] = array(
'#type' => 'button',
```

to `$form['attributes']['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',`

Comment: tried that but don't works.

Comment: if i undersand right: 1. create_report_form() works and gives you working button 2.reports_add_conditions() also works and gives working button. 3. reports_add_attribute_conditions() .... not working? Correct?

Comment: also i doubt that calling drupal_render() is good idea

Comment: @NabajitRoy see my suggestions answer below